# Magento 2 Reorder programmatically

Tags: magento-2.1, sales-order

I wish to reorder programmatically I'm about to start it but not sure from where do I start.

I'm adding products to cart programmatically rest will done by Magento from Cart to Checkout.

So while adding product to cart how can I mark that it's reorder from particular order ID like 2.

Any suggestion? I've checked reoder controller

`vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/AbstractController/Reorder.php`

But not getting idea to mark order as reorder.

Comment: Have you got any solution reorder programmatically? I am facing issue in programmatically reorder.
Please share your solution.

Comment: @KirtiNariya yes sure, I'll share in 24 hours.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I will check.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Magento default reorder action. Before execute controller, add order to registry "current_order".
You can also copy code from execute method.

```
public function execute()
{
    orderId = 2;
    $order = $this->_orderFactory->load($orderId);
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
    $cart = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
    $items = $order->getItemsCollection();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        try {
            $cart->addOrderItem($item);
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            if ($this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Checkout\Model\Session')->getUseNotice(true)) {
                $this->messageManager->addNotice($e->getMessage());
            } else {
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
            }
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/history');
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('We can\'t add this item to your shopping cart right now.'));
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('checkout/cart');
        }
    }

    $cart->save();
}
```

Remember about DI and add correct factories.

Comment: Okay I understand, Thanks for the code I'll try it out and will let you know.

Comment: class `Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart` already deprecated.
But unfortunately there is no method like `addOrderItem()` :(

Core controller  `\Magento\Sales\Controller\Order\Reorder` is still using this deprecated class